# Can I use Opera Mail as just a MUA?

Tags: maildir, opera-mail

Can I use Opera Mail as just a MUA for my mailbox in the Maildir format?

I use separated MRA (`fetchmail` + filter on `procmail`). MRA receive my mail from server to local mailbox in Maildir format. I need MUA for reading and work with my mail. So far I use Mutt, but I want to natively view HTML letters, use tagging instead of foldering, etc. I want to use Opera Mail, because I already use Opera as browser and RSS-aggregator.

I use Linux.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Maildir directly in Opera Mail. On Linux, however, you can set up a local IMAP server (such as Dovecot), which is much more widely supported.